# pyspark pivoting data with multiple aggregation is much longer/freezes compared to running separately

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot

I would like to turn a user long format to a wide format, e.g.:

`user| day| metric 1| metric 2...`  to `user| day 1 metric 1| day 2 metric 1| ..., day 1 metric 2| day 2 metric 2| ...)`.

I am using pyspark `pivot` function.

1. is this necessary to continue to spark ml or is there a trick to feed long format data to spark ml?
2. assuming this step is necessary, it seems to run endlessly on 16 nodes 4 cpu each with 30gb memory each, utilization of cpus is 100% (4). see [image]

What am I doing wrong?

The command looks like:

```
df_groupby = df.groupby('user_id')
df_aggregate_and_pivot = df_groupby.pivot('day').agg(*aggs)
```

`aggs` is just a list of aggregation function on different columsn, e.g. `f.sum(f.col(numeric_col))` or `f.first(f.col(string_col))`

### UPDATE 1

Boiled it down to the following, which is even crazier:

```
a = f.countDistinct(f.col(col_a))
b = f.first(f.col(col_b))
tic = time.time()
df_groupby = df.groupby(id_col)
df_groupby.pivot(pivot_col, pivot_distinct_values).agg(a, b).count()
toc=time.time()
print(toc-tic)
```

returns in 548.1 sec (!!!)

However, just on `a` returns in 7.1 sec:

```
df_groupby.pivot(pivot_col, pivot_distinct_values).agg(a).count()
```

Moreover, the counterpart of running just on `b` returns in 3.9 sec

```
df_groupby.pivot(pivot_col, pivot_distinct_values).agg(b).count()
```

Very strange and nonlinear, why would aggregate the `a` and `b` operation together take about 50 times more than on each independently?! I would expect the opposite as doing both operations together saves time on the `groupby`

### UPDATE 2

caching the dataframe before the groupby.pivot operation didn't help

Comment: how long is your list of aggs?

Comment: thank you @Paul, see an update, even with just 2 columns I see strange behavior.

Comment: very strange indeed. Have you monitored the number of tasks and the time they take in the spark UI? This can be insightful. I've experienced some jobs that have quadratic time in the number of aggregates which is due to very long execution plans. However this only appeared  with 10+ aggregations. Shouldn't happen with only 2. One more thing on the timing: Could you please time with completely materializing the dataframe to parquet? I think the way you time might not work correctly since you only need the count and spark might optimize something away there ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to make it work, but ... I don't understand why it fixes the issue. I encourage Spark Dev team to have a look at why this works better than the naive approach.

I had a group of several aggregation lists of lists, rather than sending all of them to `pivot` I computed them one by one and then joined the result. This ran much faster, about 100 seconds instead of 500: Each item in `agg_list` is a *list* of functions on a family type (e.g. num/str etc) with aliases e.g. `f.sum(f.col(col_name)).alias(col_name)`

```
df_groupby = df.groupby(groupby_col)
df_pivot = df_groupby.pivot(pivot_col, pivot_distinct_values)
pivot_list = [df_pivot.agg(*a) for a in agg_list] 
pivot_join = join_dataframes(pivot_list, on=self.user_id_col)
```

where `join_dataframes` is a small utility function:

```
def join_dataframes(df_list: List[pyspark.sql.DataFrame], *args, **kwargs) -> pyspark.sql.DataFrame:
    """joins multiple :class:`DataFrame` with the same `on` and `how`

    pass on, how etc like in join(other, on=None, how=None) method of pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame instance

    :param df_list: a list of dataframes
    :type df_list: List[pyspark.sql.DataFrame]
    :return: the joined pyspark dataframe
    :rtype: pyspark.sql.DataFrame
    """

    df_joined = df_list[0]
    for df in df_list[1:]:
        df_joined.join(df, *args, **kwargs)
    return df_joined
```

Comment: glad you found a solution. If you want to speed it up furthermore you could try to repartition the dataframe by your groupby column first. Then pivoting as well as joins should be faster

Comment: Thanks, it was a crazy bug. I don't even understand why my solution works. If you have time for a video conference I can show you my code and discuss what's going on. Why would reparation help? It will shuffle the data anyway, won't it? Like the reparations happens automatically in the group by. Unless I pre repatriation before to disk